# 'children' is not defined - in React class component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, children

So, I have a stateless component that uses 'React.Children.map()' that I want to turn into a class component to add it a state, but since I cannot (that I know about) pass {children} as an property anymore, I get the error saying that 'children' is not defined. How can I define children?

Original stateless component:

```
import React from 'react';

const Tabs = ({ children }) => (
  <div className="tabsPanel" onClick={clickHandler}>
    {React.Children.map(children, child =>
      React.cloneElement(child, { clickHandler: () => console.log('clicked') })
    )}
  </div>
);

export default Tabs;
```

class component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Tabs extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="tabsPanel">
        {React.Children.map(children, child =>
          React.cloneElement(child, {
            clickHandler: () => console.log('clicked', child.props.children),
          })
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Tabs;
```

Comment: use `this.props.children`, because in functional component you are destructuring children from props same as props.children, but in Class component it will be available in `this.props.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have not defined the `children` variable in your render method. The props are given as first argument to a function component, but they are available at `this.props` in a class component.

```
class Tabs extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="tabsPanel">
        {React.Children.map(this.props.children, child =>
          React.cloneElement(child, {
            clickHandler: () => console.log('clicked', child.props.children),
          })
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: `they are available at this.props in a class component.` Was the answer I was seeking